# List of DELETE operations associated with a database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server database. The database is legacy and not designed by myself. Now my job is to support this legacy database. The database include about 2000 tables, mass procedures, views, is actively manipulated by jobs and replications, maybe something else. I noticed, that data of some database tables, for instance data from table **dbo.TableA**, are regularly partially deleting. The issue is that now I need to add some additional logic into deleting process or at least switch off this deleting, but after some investigation I still can't identify what actually is deleting data from tables. I believe it should be some database or server object (stored procedure, job, replication, etc.) but I have no idea what exactly doing this magic with data. Is there any way to identify the object that is deleting table data?

Comment: Adding an `ON DELETE` trigger and logging to call stack / user might give you a clue.

Comment: SQL Server profiler is also another option.

Comment: Search all database objects for `DELETE FROM dbo.TableA` (with and without schema in case it was/wasn't used).

Comment: Or SQL Server XEvents, which will give you the full call stack as well as the host name, IP address and a buch of other stuff